# in codeigniter is there any way to check if ( $this->db->group_start(); ) i.e group is already started. or any trick to do that

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In short description, what is want is to check if

```
$this->db->group_start();
```

is already started.Basically I want the same thing like this

```
if(session_id())
{
    session_start();
}
```

Here we check if session_id is set and then start the session, I want same kind of trick to check if group has started or not so that can I start it where ever I need.

EDIT: I can do it with Boolean variable but I want to check if there is any in build feature or trick to do that.I have checked codeigniter documentation and found nothing for that.

Comment: its just an query instance, not like session id.

Comment: I just gave example... I want something like that

Comment: I mean is there any way to check this query instance group has started or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If see Query Builder source, you find that it marks a group status in the variable

```
/**
 * QB WHERE group started flag
 *
 * @var bool
 */
protected $qb_where_group_started   = FALSE;
```

There is no regular method to extend  Query Builder  class :( to check the protected property.

So, the way seems to create you own functions to manipulate groups